# Hibernate creating entry but not setting FK in @OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I do have 2 entitys, which are connected via `@OneToOne` annotation. First my classes for better understanding:

2nd Entity:

```
@Table(name = "REASON_FOR_CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT_REVERSAL")
@Entity
public class ReversalReason implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3338809410372872259L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer code;

    private boolean tax;
    private boolean currency;
    private boolean amountChange;
    private boolean locationChange;
    private boolean recipient;
    private boolean period;

    public ReversalReason() {

    }
}
```

Base entity:

```
@Table(name = "CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT")
@Entity
public class ClientChequePayment extends BaseDomainObject implements Serializable {
    /** Serial version UID */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1988633355L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer code;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "code", nullable = true)
    private ReversalReason reasonForReversal;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String proposeReversalUser;
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true)
    private String displayCode;
    @Column(length = 50)
    private String originalEntry;

    private PaymentStatus originalPaymentStatus;
```

I did ommit some fields because otherwise the code would be too much. Now lets go to the problem:

In my program I want to be able to set the field `reasonForReversal` of `ClientChequePayment` with calling `session.update(clientChequePayment);`. I checked if the field was set before calling `update` and it was. The problem is, that hibernate does create a entry for `ReversalReason`, but it does not set the PK of `ReversalReason` as FK in `ClientChequePayment` entry. Because of that, i can create several `ReversalReason` enries for 1 `ClientChequePayment`.

Is my mapping correct (I have no need to acces `ClientChequePayment` via `ReversalReason`, but vice versa)? Should the mapping be bi-directional even tho its not needed?

Comment: I'm assuming "CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT" has a column named "code", is that correct?

Comment: @MárioFernandes thats right. do i have to rename the columns or is there another workaround?

Comment: This is somewhat strange, are the primary keys from both tables the same (both named 'code')? Because that's what the code is saying. If not then you're missing the foreign key entirely

Comment: both entities do have the PK column named `code`, but they do not contain the same values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments.

That's the problem, you need a column that has a foreign key to `REASON_FOR_CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT_REVERSAL`.

Meaning, your table `CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT` needs a foreign key to `REASON_FOR_CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT_REVERSAL`, something like `id_reversal_reason` and then you can do:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_reversal_reason", nullable = true)
private ReversalReason reasonForReversal;
```

The join column is on the owning table for source table.

A snippet from `name` from the `@JoinColumn` javadocs:

```
(Optional) The name of the foreign key column.
 * The table in which it is found depends upon the
 * context.
 * <ul>
 * <li>If the join is for a OneToOne or ManyToOne
 *  mapping using a foreign key mapping strategy,
 * the foreign key column is in the table of the
 * source entity or embeddable.
```

Comment: in my `CLIENT_CHEQUE_PAYMENT` table i have a column called `reasonForReversal` which should hold the foreign key. i thought `@JoinColumn` would have to point to the record i want to fetch. anyways, i will try your suggestion

Comment: then that's the column you should use :)

Comment: it was my pleasure :)